# seekg fails when called on empty stringstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, stringstream, seekg

Here is my problem. I want to read several times a string from a stringstream, so I use 
**seekg(0)** to reset the current position to the beginning of my stream.

```
std::string l_EmptyString;
std::stringstream l_Stream;
l_Stream << l_EmptyString;
std::string l_FirstString = l_Stream.str();
l_Stream.clear();
l_Stream.seekg(0); // <-- l_Stream is set to failbit not eof not badbit ...
[...]
std::string l_SecondString = l_Stream.str();
[...]
```

But the stringstream seems to initialize the offset to -1 for empty string.
Then seekg that checks offest, sets the failbit error.

Any idea to handle this case ?

N.B : I'm using VS2005.

Comment: Why are you using such an old compiler?

Comment: Because I have to use it for my job :) Do you think it was a bug in this version of the stl ?

Comment: Most likey because I can't reproduce the error on the current version.